# Can I have unregistered guests at my hotel room?

Tags: hotels

I'll be staying in Paris for several weeks and I am planning to stay at an Ibis hotel. I want to know if I am able to invite unregistered guests during the day (not to sleep, eat, or take advantage of any other service). Or if I have to pay a fee.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Some hotels will allow unregistered guests at your hotel room, while some hotels can give you a fine due to unregistered guests to come at a certain time, or too many unregistered guests.